# formatting NSDecimalNumber issue

Tags: iphone, formatting, fractions, nsdecimalnumber

I'm trying to create NSDecimalNumber with simply format like: 123.00  with two fractional digits after dot, always. I tried use the NSFormatter and many other ways like converting float from string and creating then NSDecimalNumber from this string, but it's not working. 
The problem is that I need only NSDecimalNumber in this format, not NSString or any other.
Thanks for any advice,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You may get idea from this.

```
float num = 123.1254546;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",num];
NSLog(@"%.2f %@",num,str);
```

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, but this is not exactly what I need.  I need as result  NSDecimalNumber, not  NSString. I know the way to display it in correct format, but if I'm trying convert proper NSString like "123.00" to NSDecimalNumber, then this value is again converted to 123 inside NSDecimalNumber. I think that proper way is to use NSNumberFormatter but I can't find similar example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to do Type Casting operation for Two times as bellow

```
   float value = 123.562;
   int myDigit = value;
```

it gives value 123 in myDigit variable

```
 NSLog(@"MyDigit in Decimal = %d",myDigit);
```

**Output is MyDigit in Decimal = 123**

now if you want output like 123.000 then simply write as bellow

```
 float valueWithZiro = myDigit;

 NSLog(@"MyDigit with 000  == %3f",valueWithZiro);
```

**Output is MyDigit in Decimal = 123.000**

Answer (score 0):

NSDecimalNumber, like NSNumber, cannot contain formatting information. The object structure simply doesn't support it. It represents a number, not the way the number is displayed.

You can convert it to a formatted NSString (which you say you don't want). But you can't do what you're asking.

You convert it to a formatted NSString using an NSNumberFormatter. It's the object that allows you to specify the decimal and thousands separators, number of decimal places to display, the currency symbol, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were looking to **store** a NSNumberDecimal with just two digits after the fraction? 
If so `NSDecimalNumberBehaviors` is your friend.
I had a similar need and used the following:

```
self.decimalHandlingBehaviorForApp = [NSDecimalNumberHandler
                                         decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundUp
                                         scale:2 raiseOnExactness:NO 
                                         raiseOnOverflow:NO raiseOnUnderflow:NO
                                         raiseOnDivideByZero:YES];
```

Edit: added example of using it

```
// update the taxable total first
self.cartTaxableTotal = [self.cartTaxableTotal decimalNumberByAdding:itemAdded.priceOfItem
                                                        withBehavior:self.decimalHandlingBehaviorForApp];
```